# Filter RSS XML via XSLT on SharePoint

Tags: xml, xslt, rss, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to add a Massachusetts Bay Transit Authority (MBTA) Service Alerts feed to my company SharePoint that I am developing. The feed is permanently housed at http://realtime.mbta.com/alertsrss/rssfeed4. To me, the Tree appears to be:

```
<rss>
   <channel>
      <item>
          <title>
          <description>
          <category>
          <guid>
          <pubdate>
```

The problem I am running into is how to filter out specific alerts based on their category. I am new to `XSLT` and backwards engineered a demo from w3schools (example here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).

The following is the code I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>T-Alerts</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Description</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
 </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now the two issues I have is how to only select only alerts with categories that contain, Commuter Rail, Subway and Bus but also have a pubdate time within the last 4 hours.

The second issue, is when I run this, it only returns 5 results, even through there are about 100. Screenshot is here: [image: XSLT_Example.png].

I've been scouring the internet, but being so new XSLT, I have not been able to get this to work.

Edit: I have gotten it to select specific categories, now I am stuck at filtering out the times so that it is only posts in the last 6 hours, and also how to display them as separate catagories (Bus Alerts, Subway Alerts, yadda yadda). My updated code is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>T-Alerts</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#4f6701">
    <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Alert Date</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item[category='Bus'], rss/channel/item[category='Boat'], rss/channel/item[category='Subway'], rss/channel/item[category='Subway, Commuter Rail'], rss/channel/item[category='Commuter Rail']">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="pubDate"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
 </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's usually best to avoid asking two things in one question. Having said that, for you second issue, it's probably due to W3Schools not being very robust. Try http://xsltransform.net/ for a more reliable on-line transformer, and you will see your XSLT does return all rows.

Comment: @Tim C. Thanks for the reference. The only thing I noticed from that site, was it does not like the "&" symbol that is in some of the return data. But true to what you said, after replacing those, it did pull all the info out, great tip!